# PHP/HTML - Trouble with form inputs - Turning multiple post's into just one

Tags: php, html, forms, button, input

I am busy creating an order system.

I am having issues trying to create a form that requires only one order button.

Currently the form is for each product result. The user has the ability to enter in a quantity desired of a certain product, then can order the product based on the quantity chosen. The item id and quantity chosen are then added to sessions.

The problem with this, is that if there are 5 items, there are 5 order buttons.

I am trying to simplify this, where for 5 products, there will be only one order button controlling the entire selection of products.

Here is the code relating to this:

```
//Now we search for our search term, in the field the user specified 

$dataQuery = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE upper(`desc`) LIKE '%" 
   . implode("%' AND upper(`desc`) LIKE '%", $keywords_array) 
   . "%' ORDER BY `desc`";

$data = mysql_query($dataQuery) or die(mysql_error());

$tempVar = 0;
//And we display the results 
while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
$prId = $result['id'];
$prRefCode = $result['refCode'];
$prDesc = $result['desc'];
$prPack = $result['pack'];
$prMeasure = $result['measure'];
$prQuantity = $result['quantity'];
$prDeptCode = $result['deptCode'];
$prTaxable = $result['taxable'];
$prPrice1 = $result['price1'];
$prPrice2 = $result['price2'];
$prCrdCode = $result['crdCode'];
$prCost1 = $result['cost1'];
$prCost2 = $result['cost2'];

if ($tempVar == 0) {
$pageContent .= '
<p><u>All prices are inclusive of VAT</u></p>
<table class="searchResults" border="1" align="center" width="90%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Stock Code</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Packsize</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>In-Stock?</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Submit</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
';
}

    $pageContent .= '
<tr>
    <td>' . $prId . '</td>
    <td>' . $prDesc . '</td>
    <td>' . $prPack . 'x' . $prSize . ' ' . $prMeasure . '</td>
    <td>R' . $prPrice1 . '</td>
';
    if (empty($prQuantity)) {
        $pageContent .= '
<td>No</td>
';
    } else {
        $pageContent .= '
<td>Yes</td>
';
    }
    $pageContent .= '
    <form id="validated" action="" method="post">
    <td>            
            <div>
                <input type="text" 
onkeydown="return ( event.ctrlKey || event.altKey 
                || (47<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<58 && event.shiftKey==false) 
                || (95<event.keyCode && event.keyCode<106)
                || (event.keyCode==8) || (event.keyCode==9) 
                || (event.keyCode>34 && event.keyCode<40) 
                || (event.keyCode==46) )" 
                name="quantity" size ="2" 
                value ="1" 
                style="background: #F4F4F4;
                       font-family: Monaco, monospace;" />
            </div>            
    </td>
    <td>
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="' . $prId . '" />
                <input type="submit" name="action" value="Order" />
            </div>            
    </td>
    </form>     
</tr>
';
$tempVar ++;
}



//This counts the number of results - and if there wasn't any it gives them a little message explaining that 
$anymatches = mysql_num_rows($data);
if ($anymatches == 0) {
    $pageContent .= '
<p>Sorry, but we can not find an entry to match your query</p>
<!-- end .aliLeft --></div>
';
}

if ($anymatches > 0 and count($tempVar) == count($anymatches)) {
    $pageContent .= '
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- end .aliLeft --></div>
';
}
```

And here is the code controlling the instance of a user clicking on the order button:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['order']))
{
$_SESSION['order'] = array();
}

if (!isset($_SESSION['quantity']))
{
$_SESSION['quantity'] = array();
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'Order' and $_POST['quantity'] > 0)
{
// Add item to the end of the $_SESSION['order'] array
$_SESSION['order'][$_POST['id']] = $_POST['id'];
$_SESSION['quantity'][$_POST['id']] = $_POST['quantity'];
header('Location: .');
exit();
}
```

And here is the code that configures the quantity value for totalling the order:

```
$total = 0;
if (count($order) > 0)
{
foreach ($order as $product)
{
    mysql_data_seek( $totalsSql, 0);  //<- this line, to reset the pointer for every EACH.
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($totalsSql))
    {
     $prodId = $row['id'];
     $prodPrice1 = $row['price1'];
     $prodQuantity = $quantity[$prodId];
    if ($product == $prodId) 
        {
        $total += ($prodPrice1*$prodQuantity);
        break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

As you can see, when the user searches for a product, the mysql table is queried, if results are found, then they are returned.

In this process, the form is created for each result.

What I am trying to do, is extend this form to cover the entire set of results, then have only one input for "Order", so essentially, the user can enter quantities on various products, then have those products and quantities added to their order.

Does anyone have any advice on how i would go about this task?

I would appreciate any input what so ever, thank you!

Comment: First, don't use the same `ID` markup value twice. They should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encode the product identifier in the field name:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="…" name="quantity<?php echo $prId; ?>" size ="2" value ="1" style="…" />
```

In your process script you then do something like:

```
foreach ($_POST as $sKey => $sQuantity) {
    if (preg_match('/^quantity([1-9][0-9]*)$/DX', $sKey, $asMatch) === 1) {
        // User added $sQuantity times product $asMatch[1]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would change the name for each input to `quantity[$id]` where `id` is the id for each field. You would get that result back as an associative array in php where the key is the id you have provided between the [].

That way, you can iterate over the array and process multiple fields.